# Function bringing back error 'token {'?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm having a hard time with functions. I tried this:

```
(function data {     // This is the part that's broken it seems?
                var data = 1;
                var real = 2;
                console.log(data + real) //
})
```

I get back the error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`

I'm not sure what that means though?

Comment: Where's the arguments' list?

Comment: You forgot to provide the parenthesis to allow for parameters (even if you don't use any). `(function data() {` should be that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems to me, you are a bit confused with the brackets...
Try something like this:

```
function data(){
    var data = 1;
    var real = 2;
    console.log(data+real);
}
```

The error suggests there is a problem with a token he didn't expect to be there...

Hope this helps!

Comment: why is it when I test this out in chrome's console it brings back the result 'undefined' ? it's not an error I think..but it doesn't bring up the console log? edit: oh right I need to call the function! Never mind, thank you! I will check your answer once the times up.

Answer (score 1):

The error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` exactly what is says, there was `{`, but parser expected something else, which is missing parameters brackets.

JavaScript, like most (all?) C-related programming languages, require you to put brackets for parameters, even if you don't expect any.

```
(function data { ...
```

should be

```
(function data() { // This is the part that's broken it seems?
    var data = 1;
    var real = 2;
    console.log(data + real) //
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The function should be written

```
function data(){
```

There's no real need for the parenthesis before the keyword function, but you need them after the function name to provide parameters, even if you have none.